# while Installing `yum install python -pip` getting the below error in HDP 2.5

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hdp, hortonworks-sandbox

http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.4.0.0-1225/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: AMBARI.2.4.0.0-2.x. Please verify its path and try again
[root@sandbox maria_dev]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]# cp sandbox.repo /tmp
cp: cannot stat `sandbox.repo': No such file or directory
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]#

---

I tried these commands in the root

```
[root@sandbox maria_dev]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]# cp sandbox.repo /tmp
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]# rm sandbox.repo
```

---

I am using HDP 2.5

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a repo try

```
yum clean all
```

Then try again.

Also suggest, listing the files in the directory since your error says it doesn't exist:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d 
ls -al
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I followed the same strategy deleting every file the error mention, I just did the same thing you did deleting sandbox.repo and copying them somewhere safe for backup.
I d like to mention that I just started learning about big data and Hadoop ecosystem, this method worked and I installed python-pip on HDP 2.5 but I don't know if I'm going to face problems in the future caused by deleting those files.